# Is the behavior of this user reasonable? What can I do about it?

Tags: discussion, reputation

On my question here [Why should I use foreign keys in database?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/375704/why-should-i-use-foreign-keys-in-database/375705?noredirect=1#comment825365_375705), this user @jaymee has constantly been bugging me. I ignored his first comment. Then he comment on the accepted answer. I replied to him then that I have accepted the answer to my question and he shouldn't be concerned about it but he constantly jumps in and tries to school me.

Even when I tag other user in commeent (in reply to them), the jumps in and tries to lecture, "you are not listing at all", etc etc.

I couldn't find a way to report him on his profile. what are my options and is this behaviour reasonable? You can bug someone once but he is at this question again and again and even downvoted it (which I am fine with).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I see very little wrong with this behavior.

I only see two questionable statements - the one calling the question "silly" and the one indicating that "you're not listening at all". Those statements seem unnecessary.

When you post a question, people can engage with it in multiple ways. Leaving comments is one such way. You can choose to ignore the comments or engage with the commenter and try to find ways to address the comments. One purpose of a comment is to expression uncertainty or confusion about what you are looking for in the question in order to be able to provide (or to allow others to provide) a good answer, and that seems to be the intent here.

I don't see any reason to take action on these comments. Although I would advise that if you don't want to engage with a user, simply ignore them. If they are being rude or offensive in comments, you can flag those particular comments. But nothing in that question or on any of the answers appears to be rude or offensive.

Comment: Yes I did ignore his first comment, then he commented again I said to him that I have accepted the answer already so there is should be no issue with question. He kept engaging negatively, I told him I don't need 'his intelligence'. That chat was later removed. The comment above you see was after I told him, "I do not need his intellegence" but he is stuck on this question.

Comment: @Noname You may think that there is no issue with the question, but Stack Exchange is not about helping *you* get an answer to *your question*. It's about building a repository of questions and answers to help the broader community. If someone thinks that they can provide a better answer with additional information about your problem or your current state, then they can and should attempt to engage. The fact that you accepted an answer that helps you is irrelevant to this. You can either choose to engage and allow others to provide good answers or ignore. If you do not want to engage, don't.

Comment: He was not interested in answering at all. He was lecturing me, where are you going with this, you are not getting it, he did not provide any help or any answer, just schooling. Constructive comments were from other users.

Comment: @Noname If you don't think I get it, that's fine. You can wait for someone else's take. But I see absolutely nothing wrong with anything that you've pointed out that requires moderator intervention. There is nothing rude or offensive about the comments that remain on the question or answers.

Comment: I agree it does not need moderator at this point but at least I want to get an opinion about such behavior coz I dont see if often. Thanks for answering!